# How to get value of asp:Button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I don't understand very well how I get value of  with JavaScript or JQuery?

I have this code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnIdButton" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
```

In this case I need get value inside the button with id "btnIdButton". I tested some possibilites:

```
$("#btnIdButton").val()
$('input[id*=btnIdButton]').value()
$("#btnIdButton").text()
document.getElementById("#btnIdButton")
```

But it did not work.

Comment: 1) ASP.Net webforms changes the `id` when the button is rendered on the client - you need to get the `ClientID` property and use that to select the button. 2) The button has no `value` for you to retrieve, you need to use `text()`

Comment: When you say use **text** would be $("#btnIdButton").text?

Comment: If you don't want the ID of your button to change, you can set `ClientIdMode` to `static` at the control, page, or application levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "endsWith" selector like this:`$("[id$=btnIdButton]")`

Comment: Nice guy, with your example and .text.  $("[id$=btnIdButton]").text() it worked!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getASPButtonValue() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID %>");
        alert("ASP.NET Button Value= "+btn.value);
    }

    function getHTMLButtonValue() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("btnhtml");
         alert("HTML Button Value= "+btn.value);
     }
</script>

    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="getASPButtonValue();" Text="Button" />
        <input type="button" id="btnhtml" onclick="getHTMLButtonValue();" value="HTML BUTTON" />
    </div>
```

[image: Click to see Out Put Screen]

Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

you can access your button in js
$("#<%=btnIdButton.ClientID%>")
or use ClientIDMode property of your button